# Meaning of CODE_ANALYSIS compilation symbol/constant

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

What's the real thing with this compilation constant for vs2012 projects?

I've read that it's to have Code Analysis consider SuppressMessage attributes during analysis, but both with and without this flag, in VS2012 or FxCop, the SuppressMessages are considered and the code warnings ignored.

Comment: Yes, but you have to use macros.  Check the bottom of include\CodeAnalysis\sourceannotations.h

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is C#. I inspected the compiled assembly, and even without this flag the SuppressMessage is there. Now I'm confused!

Comment: No, that works just fine.  The C# compiler does not have a bug handling [Conditional].

Comment: #ifdef CODE_ANALYSIS
#define SA_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( category, id, ... ) [::System::Diagnostics::CodeAnalysis::SuppressMessage( category, id, __VA_ARGS__ )]
#define CA_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( ... ) [System::Diagnostics::CodeAnalysis::SuppressMessage( __VA_ARGS__ )]
#define CA_GLOBAL_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( ... ) [assembly:System::Diagnostics::CodeAnalysis::SuppressMessage( __VA_ARGS__ )]
#else  // !CODE_ANALYSIS
#define SA_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( category, id, ... )
#define CA_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( ... )
#define CA_GLOBAL_SUPPRESS_MESSAGE( ... ) 
#endif  // !CODE_ANALYSIS

Comment: What's the meaning of that?